# Google Maps Not Displaying - Weird Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am writing an app that has Google Maps in it. All the code appears to be correct but the map simply does not show up. I get these two errors:
`Uncaught QuotaExceededError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'plnkr_dirty_exit' exceeded the quota.`
and
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` 
Here is a plnkr of my work: http://plnkr.co/edit/AiVc6nccqke8Jluonpxl?p=preview 
Here is the code that pertains to Google Maps: 
app.js

```
(function() {
  angular.module("siteLookUpApplication", ["ngRoute"]);

  angular.module("siteLookUpApplication").config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/search", {
        templateUrl: "search.html",
        controller: "searchController"
      })
      .when("/map/:locationName/:locationCoords", {
        templateUrl: "map.html",
        controller: "mapController"
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/search'
      });
  });
}());
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="siteLookUpApplication">
  <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type='text/css'/>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC0wdLb9-Os4YVxn_JR2sY08xEN-1aJkMM"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.17" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.17" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="map-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="search-controller.js"></script>

    <title>Site ID</title>
  </head>

  <body link="white" vlink="white">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1>Site Finder</h1>

      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

map.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div ng-controller="mapController" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div link="blue" vlink="blue"><a ng-href="#/search">Back To Search</a></div>
    <p>Map for {{locationName}}</p>

    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

map-controller.js

```
(function() {
  function mapController($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.locationCoords = $routeParams.locationCoords;
    $scope.locationName = $routeParams.locationName;
    function initialize() {
      var center = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.locationCoords);
      var mapOptions = {
        center: center,
        zoom: 5
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  }

  angular.module("siteLookUpApplication").controller("mapController", mapController);
}());
```

I thought the problem was that `initialize();` was not being called but I believe it is called when the page loads here `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` inside `map-controller.js` 
I have also tried using `ng-init` and `onLoad` to initialize the map
I have had this issue for a while now and i'm all out of ideas. Can anyone tell me why it won't work? Thanks in advance.

P.S. Would you consider using AngularUI for this?

Comment: `setting the value of 'plnkr_dirty_exit' exceeded the quota` sounds more like a problem with Plunker than Google Maps

Comment: @duncan That's what I was thinking too but I included it anyway.